# The containsAll method return incorrect results when there are duplicate elements in the compared List in Java

Tags: java

The first List is [5,5,3,7,6] and named FirstList, another List is [5,5,5] and named SecList. When I invoke containsAll method like this `FirstList.containsAll(SecList)` to see if FirstList contains SecList. Obviously the answer is false, but the containsAll method return true, it's a incorrect results.

The whole code is as follows:

```
    List<Integer> FirstList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> SecList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        SecList.add(5);
    }

    FirstList.add(5);
    FirstList.add(5);
    FirstList.add(3);
    FirstList.add(7);
    FirstList.add(6);
    System.out.println("FirstList: " + FirstList);
    System.out.println("SecList: " + SecList);
    System.out.println("FirstList contains SecList?  " + FirstList.containsAll(SecList));
```

And the output is:

```
FirstList: [5,5,3,7,6]
SecList: [5,5,5]
FirstList contains SecList? true
```

It seems like this method can only produce correct results if the list does not contain duplicate elements. Is there any way to achieve this logic simply? Please forgive my poor English, and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `.contains` and `.containsAll` are `Collection` methods. Not all collections support duplicates, to start with. And the logic is just: if you search each element of this collection, can you find an element equal to it in that collection? And that's true for your example.

Comment: Because the `second` list has only three elements, then `first` list contains all the same elements, so it becomes `true`.  It's possible that a check should be done to determine if the two lists have the same size, but this is an implementation detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Obviously the answer is false,"

The answer is true, and supposed to be true.  For each element `e` in `SecList`, `FirstList.contains(e)` returns true.  That's how `containsAll` is supposed to work; there's no bug here.

If you want that behavior, you will need to *count* elements in each collection, perhaps with a `Map<E, Integer>` or a Guava `Multiset`, and then compare the counts of each element.